# Sort Single Dimensional Array of NSDate objects in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift2, nsdate

Are there any functions in Swift 2 that will sort single-dimensional `Array`s of `NSDate` in ascending or descending order without writing my own sorting algorithm?

I've tried the following, but `>` cannot be used to compare two NSDate objects unfortunately.

```
var array = [NSDate]()
array.sort { $0 < $1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, one way of doing this:

```
public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}
```

And then just sort dates like you want:

```
var array = [NSDate]()
array.sort { $0 < $1 }
```

Comment: Tthere is already a `==` operator for `NSObject`, there is no need to implement it for subclasses (like `NSDate`).

Comment: @MartinR, your are right

Answer (score 1):

You can take pacification's answer one step further by also declaring that `NSDate` conforms to `Comparable`:

```
public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqualToDate(rhs)
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

extension NSDate: Comparable { }
```

Then you can use `sort()` without providing a comparator:

```
let dates = [NSDate]()
dates.sort()
```